# SQL CONVERT STRING

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I do struggle with some of these conversions, so I do apologize, I have asked a similar question in the past, but just can't get my head around how to achieve this.

So a value of 50.00 is currently being exported into the following format -

```
000000000000050000
```

A value of 25.99 would look like

```
000000000000025990
```

This is a 18 character field where any leading characters are padded with a zero.

What I am trying to do is convert that to a 19 character string  - still with leading zeros - but the value of 50 or 25.99 is slightly different -

`000000000000050000` becomes `0000000000000005000`

`000000000000025990` becomes `0000000000000002599`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for T-SQL `SUBSTRING` function

Comment: How is the 18 character conversion done?

Comment: The answers given below perfectly translate the string to what you want. Remember to alter the field that will contain the new numbers to nvarchar(19)

ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN somecolumn nvarchar(19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would appear to want:

```
select '00' + left(str, 17)
```

This is a very strange format.  Perhaps you should consider using `numeric`/`decimal`, which can accurately represent the number.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of assumptions go into this answer, but...

```
SELECT '00'+LEFT(OriginalField, 17)
```

That would truncate your original 18th character and simply put two more zero's on the front.

The solution is not so simple if you need to potentially round up the 17th character.